# How to use window.location() in jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, window.location

How to use window.location method in jquery mobile. As am i developing an app using jquery mobile i need to change from one html page to other html page where i need to use window.location(). I know that to use

```
  $.mobile.changePage( "page", { transition: "slide"} );
```

But here when using changePage() method getting problem with some js files. So, i thought of going to window.location() method.

As i am using the code is...

index.html

```
<section id="previewPage" data-role="page">
  <div data-role="content" id="previewId" class="previewScreen">
    <select name="select-choice-0" id="select-choice-1" data-native-menu="false">
        <option value="email">Share via Email</option>
        <option value="bbm" data-location='bbmIntegration.html'>Share via BBM</option>
        <option value="sms">Share via SMS</option>
        <option value="facebook">Share via Facebook</option>
        <option value="twitter">Share via Twitter</option>
        <option value="google">Share via Google</option>
    </select>                       
  </div>
</section>
```

sharingScreen.js

```
$('#select-choice-1').change(function() {
     window.location = $(this).data('location');
    //window.location = $('#select-choice-1').data('location')  
  });
```

When i **click on Share via BBM** , my html page needs to navigate to **bbmIntegration.html** page. But when i am running this **in chrome browser when i click on Share via BBM it is displaying as "File /BBM/sample/www/undefined not found".** can anyone please help me with this where i am doing the mistake...

Thanks in advance.........

Comment: First of all window.location is a property and no function, but you use it as a property so far this does not matter. Try to replace the $(this) with $('#select-choice-1')

Comment: i tried like that also by replacing the id, then also getting the same problem as undefined. Not getting any idea where the mistake is...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Try this:

  $('#select-choice-1').change(function() {
    window.location = $(this).find("option:selected").data('location');

  });​
```

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, your js is looking for a data attribute on the `select` tag - it needs to be looking at the selected `option` tag:

```
$('#select-choice-1').change(function() {
    window.location = $(this).find('option:selected').data('location');
}
```